# Why does input() give a SyntaxError when I just press enter?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have the following python code:

```
print 'This is a simple game.'
input('Press enter to continue . . .')
print 'Choose an option:'

...
```

But when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> button, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/4.Python/temp.py", line 2, in <module>
    input('Press enter to continue . . .')
  File "<string>", line 0
    
   ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

P.S. I am using python IDLE version 2.6 on Windows 7.

---

<sub>Related problem in IPython: [Why does the IPython REPL tell me "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing" as I input the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43189302)</sub>

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For Python 2, you want `raw_input`, not `input`. The former will read a line. The latter will read a line and try to execute it, not advisable if you don't want your code being corrupted by the person entering data.

For example, they could do something like call arbitrary functions, as per the following example:

```
def sety99():
    global y
    y = 99

y = 0
input ("Enter something: ")
print y
```

If you run that code under Python 2 and enter `sety99()`, the output will `99`, despite the fact that at no point does your code (in its normal execution flow) purposefully set `y` to anything other than zero (it does in the function but that function is never explicitly called by your code). The reason for this is that the `input(prompt)` call is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`.

See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) for the gory details.

Keep in mind that Python 3 fixes this. The [input function there](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) behaves as you would expect.

Comment: Actually, you can't *assign* anything in `eval`. However, you can call whatever destructive method you'd like, so it's hardly any better.

Comment: Or, you want to use Python 3, where `input()` does what the Python 2 `raw_input()` did.

Answer (score 4):

In Python 2, `input()` strings are evaluated, and if they are empty, an exception is raised. You probably want `raw_input()` (or move on to Python 3).

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2.x, `input()` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`.  And `eval` gives a syntax error when you pass it an empty string.

You want to use `raw_input()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `input` on Python 2.x, it is interpreted as a Python expression, which is not what you want. And since in your case, the string is empty, an error is raised.

What you need is `raw_input`. Use that and it will return a string.