# Can't install Scrapy for Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, installation, scrapy

I'm trying to install Scrapy for Python 2.7 according to [Installation guide - Scrapy 0.22.2 documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html). I've installed pip, but when I try to run the following from the Windows 8 command prompt:

```
pip install Scrapy
```

it doesn't appear to install properly, here is the end of the pip.log

```
C:\Python27\lib\disutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'butrack_url'
  warnings.warn(msg)

error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir c:\users\mgarrett\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_mgarrett...
Command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools,                           tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\mgarrett\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_mgarrett\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\mgarrett\appdata\local\temp\pip-7wgh3w-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in c:\users\mgarrett\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_mgarrett\lxml
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1435, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 706, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\mgarrett\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_mgarrett\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\mgarrett\appdata\local\temp\pip-7wgh3w-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in c:\users\mgarrett\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_mgarrett\lxml
```

I've previously installed setuptools, so I'm not sure what the log file is referring to at the end?

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Comment: I looked at the related errors but they seem to concern Visual Studio, which I'm not using.

Comment: The errors are because some of Scrapy's dependencies need a C++ compiler. You can either go fixing one dependency after the other or install scrapy from a executable. The scrapy executable are linked in this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5025939/531036

Comment: Thanks shaktimaan. I've finally got it working, I didn't realise that Scrapy required a C++ compiler.