# Python Not Outputting Correct Values

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here's the syntax of the problem I'm facing:

Heating and cooling degree-days are measured by utility companies to estimate energy requirements. If the average temperature for a day is below 60, then the number of degrees below 60 is added to the heating degree-days. If the temperature is above 80, the amount over 80 is added to the cooling degree-days. Write a program that accepts a sequence of average daily temps and computes the running total of cooling and heating degree-days. The program should print these two totals after all the data has been processed.

When I run my program, it will let me input temps, but when I press enter to signify I'm done entering in data I get the return "Unknown error". Thanks for the assistance.

```
def main():
print("Please enter daily average temperature below. Leave empty when finish.")

hdd,cdd,hot,cool = 0,0,0,0
date = 1
try:
    temp = input("Day #{} :".format(date))

    while temp != "":
        temp = int(temp)

        if temp > 80:
            cdd = (temp-80)+cdd
        if temp < 60:
            hdd = (60-temp)+hdd

        date = date+1
        temp = input("Day #{} :".format(date))

    print("In {} days, there\'r total of {} HDD and {} CDD.".format(date-1,hdd,cdd))

except ValueError:
    print('Please correct your data.')
except:
    print('Unknown error.')

main()
```

Comment: Please provide the full error without your custom error.

Comment: This is **precisely** the reason why `except:` (all exceptions) is never recommended. You have removed all facilities for troubleshooting the *actual* error. Get rid of it, and never use it again.

Comment: use `sys.exc_info()`!!!

Comment: After you take @JonathonReinhart advice, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074225/python-unexpected-eof-while-parsing

Comment: For sshashank124 here's the error: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: I always like it when it is python's fault for not outputting the correct values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`. Your `temp` variable is attemping to 'be' an int when it's null (because it's "").

It's giving you a syntax error because `input()` attempts to evaluate the expression you put in. You should stick with `raw_input()` and cast the value to whatever you need it to be until you know you actually need `input()` for something specific.

After changing both `input()`s to `raw_input()`:

```
Day #1 :1
Day #2 :2
Day #3 :3
Day #4 :90
Day #5 :90
Day #6 :
6 174 20
In 5 days, there'r total of 174 HDD and 20 CDD.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of your usage of `input()` on python 2.7. It is hitting this error:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

which your program will not display thanks to your last `except` clause.

The cause of the error is because `input()` on python 2.7 is equivalent to getting an input and executing it. In your case it is trying to execute no input.

Use `raw_input()` and your code will run fine.

More details on the error with `input()` on python 2.7 is discussed here - [Why input() gives an error when I just press enter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025920/why-input-gives-an-error-when-i-just-press-enter)