# Why does the IPython REPL tell me "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing" as I input the code?

Tags: python, syntax-error, eof

I'm getting an error while running this part of the code. I tried some of the existing solutions, but none of them helped.

```
elec_and_weather = pd.read_csv(r'C:\HOUR.csv', parse_dates=True,index_col=0)
# Add historic DEMAND to each X vector
 for i in range(0,24):
    elec_and_weather[i] = np.zeros(len(elec_and_weather['DEMAND']))
    elec_and_weather[i][elec_and_weather.index.hour==i] = 1
# Set number of hours prediction is in advance
n_hours_advance = 24

# Set number of historic hours used
n_hours_window = 24

for k in range(n_hours_advance,n_hours_advance+n_hours_window):
    elec_and_weather['DEMAND_t-%i'% k] = np.zeros(len(elec_and_weather['DEMAND']))'
```

I always get this error:

```
for i in range(0,24):
File "<ipython-input-29-db3022a769d1>", line 1
for i in range(0,24):
                     ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

File "<ipython-input-25-df0a44131c36>", line 1
    for k in range(n_hours_advance,n_hours_advance+n_hours_window):
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

---

<sub>Related problem in IDLE or the command-line REPL: [Why does input() give a SyntaxError when I just press enter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025920)</sub>

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried indentation"?

Comment: thanks for the edits

Comment: Now the code is a mess again. Please indent it properly. Your current code (as you have it now) will fail at line 3 due to incorrect indentation. I fixed your code syntax once but you edited it again making it incorrect again.

Comment: extremely sorry

Comment: Are you using the ipython/jupyter notebook or the ipython console?

Comment: i'am using ipython.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing` means that the end of your source code was reached before all code blocks were completed. A code block starts with a statement like `for i in range(100):` and requires at least one line afterwards that contains code that should be in it.

It seems like you were executing your program line by line in the ipython console. This works for single statements like `a = 3` but not for code blocks like for loops. See the following example:

```
In [1]: for i in range(100):
  File "<ipython-input-1-ece1e5c2587f>", line 1
    for i in range(100):
                        ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

To avoid this error, you have to enter the whole code block as a single input:

```
In [2]: for i in range(5):
   ...:     print(i, end=', ')
0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
```

Comment: I was confused because on the Terminal, it assumes the command isn't finished, but on the debugger console it seems to indeed not do the same

Comment: in python3.9, this returns `IndentationError: expected an indented block`

Answer (score 68):

This can simply also mean you are missing or have too many parentheses. For example this has too many, and will result in unexpected `EOF`:

```py
print(9, not (a==7 and b==6)
```

Answer (score 10):

My syntax error was semi-hidden in an f-string

```
 print(f'num_flex_rows = {self.}\nFlex Rows = {flex_rows}\nMax elements = {max_elements}')
```

should be

```
 print(f'num_flex_rows = {self.num_rows}\nFlex Rows = {flex_rows}\nMax elements = {max_elements}')
```

It didn't have the PyCharm spell-check-red line under the error.

It did give me a clue, yet when I searched on this error message, it of course did not find the error in that bit of code above.

Had I looked more closely at the error message, I would have found the '' in the error. Seeing Line 1 was discouraging and thus wasn't paying close attention  :-(  Searching for

> self.)

yielded nothing.  Searching for

> self.

yielded practically everything :-\

If I can help you avoid even a minute longer of *deskchecking* your code, then mission accomplished :-)

> C:\Python\Anaconda3\python.exe
>   C:/Python/PycharmProjects/FlexForms/FlexForm.py   File "",
>   **line 1
>       (self.)**
>             ^ SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Why would it says "error at line 1" though? This is so annoying.

Comment: I never thought about that part. That may actually be a bit of a clue. I just made that same error in a file I'm editing. If you stretch out my error message so it's not wrapped, you'll see that it says the error is in 'File "" line 1'.   In the file I'm editing now I made a bad f-string and this time I got a different error:    File "<fstring>", line 1.  So at least it's telling me that it's in an f-string.  I'm not a brilliant Python internals person. My guess is that it's treating the f-string in a file-like manner, whatever that means (sorry, I'm really stretching).

Answer (score 6):

Here is one of my mistakes that produced this exception: I had a `try` block without any `except` or `finally` blocks. This will not work:

```py
try:
    lets_do_something_beneficial()
```

To fix this, add an `except` or `finally` block:

```py
try:
    lets_do_something_beneficial()
finally:
    lets_go_to_sleep()
```

Answer (score 4):

There are some cases can lead to this issue, if it occered in the middle of the code it will be "IndentationError: expected an indented block" or "SyntaxError: invalid syntax", if it at the last line it may "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing"：

Missing the body of "if","while"and"for" statement-->

```
root@nest:~/workplace# cat test.py
l = [1,2,3]
for i in l:
root@nest:~/workplace# python3 test.py
  File "test.py", line 3

               ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Unclosed parentheses (Especially in complex nested states)-->

```
root@nest:~/workplace# cat test.py
l = [1,2,3]
print( l
root@nest:~/workplace# python3 test.py
  File "test.py", line 3

            ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error while trying to `eval` an empty string.
for example:

```
query = eval(req.body)
```

I used `json.loads()` instead and the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

`elec_and_weather['DEMAND_t-%i'% k] = np.zeros(len(elec_and_weather['DEMAND']))'`

The error comes at the end of the line where you have the (') sign; this error always means that you have a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes its due to forgetting to add an Except on a try/except statement.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31749521)

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error below:

> SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

When I forgot a trailing parenthesis as shown below:

```py
print("Hello"
             ↑
           Here
```

Or, when I forgot to put `pass` to class or function as shown below:

```py
class Person:
    # pass
```

```py
def test():
    # pass
```