# Can't define simple python function

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio

I'm trying to define a simple function. The functions below are exact copies from my .py-file.

This works fine (1):

```
def test_fun(A,B): return A*B
```

But this does not work (2)
(I run it by highlighting the entire function in my .py-file and running it in the visual studio interactive window (so not in the terminal)):

```
def test_fun(
    A,B
    ):
    return A*B
```

It gives me

```
>>> def test_fun(
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    def test_fun(
                ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
>>> A,B
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
>>> ):
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    ):
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> return A*B
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Why is that way of defining the function failing?

If I only run the first line of (2):

```
def test_fun(
```

I get the same error (that is, I don't get `...`):

```
>>> def test_fun(
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    def test_fun(
                ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Here I would expect it to give me `...`.

And to my suprise, this function below actually works (3):

```
def test_fun(
    A,B):
    return A*B
```

All my functions are defined as the (2) and they worked fine in visual studio 2017 ver. 15.5.3. I just updated to visual studio 2017 ver. 15.7.5. and now the error occurs. Does anyone know what is happening?

I'm using python 3.6.

Note that I'm **not** using Iphyton interactive mode. If I enable it (2) actually works.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem.

Comment: So is this in VS or in the terminal? Because you function that "doesn't work" worked fine for me in both!

Comment: 3.6.4 could not reproduce.

Comment: "and a list of subsequent errors."- What other errors?

Comment: Can you show the exact code without the command prompt so we can copy and paste exactly what you have?

Comment: The code you posted works fine (contrary to what I thought previously)

Comment: Do you get `...` prompt on lines after `def test_fun(`?

Comment: Possibly related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43189302/syntaxerror-unexpected-eof-while-parsing

Comment: @cdar No i dont get `...` after `def test_fun(`. Please see updated question.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Exact code shown in update. Also complete list of errors is shown.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with visual studio, which you should tag and contact your supplier.  It is not a python issue.