# im making a discord bot and i keep getting this error

Tags: python, discord

trying to make a discord bot with a port scanner and keep running into this error

````
async def scan(ctx):
    async def scan(port):
            try:
                s = socket.socket()
                s.settimeout(1)
                s.connect((ip, port))
                s.close()
                with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
                    for port in range(65500):
                        executor.submit(scan, ip, port + 1)
                        client.run(TOKEN)```

the error is                                                                              

 File "bot.py", line 94

                           ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
````

Comment: When posting syntax errors something is wrong with the syntax of your code. You should send the whole code so we know which line `line 94` corresponds to. I can see 2 syntax mistakes: 1. wrong indentation 2. `\`\`\`` random backticks.

Answer (score 1):

a `try` block needs a following `except` block. add this to your code to make it work:

```py
except:
    pass
```

or you could just remove the `try` block entirely, both solutions work. Here's what the error means

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43189302/syntaxerror-unexpected-eof-while-parsing):

> The SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing means that the end of your source code was reached before all code blocks were completed. A code block starts with a statement like for i in range(100): and requires at least one line afterwards that contains code that should be in it.