# unexpected EOF while parsing Django form function

Tags: python-3.x, django, paypal

I'm following this [tutorial](https://overiq.com/django-paypal-subscriptions-with-django-paypal/) , after adding this function in views.py to render a paypal form i get this error "unexpected EOF while parsing"

```
def subscription(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = SubscriptionForm(request.POST)
        if f.is_valid():
            request.session['subscription_plan'] = request.POST.get('plans')
            return redirect('process_subscription')
    else:
        f = SubscriptionForm()
    return render(request, 'ecommerce_app/subscription_form.html', locals()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing parenthesis at the end of your `render()` method:

```py
return render(request, 'ecommerce_app/subscription_form.html', locals()
#                                                                     ^^^
```

[SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43189302/28360)