# Python 3 - EOF Error

Tags: python-3.x, user-input

I get the following error when I try to execute this code,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\dev\tmp\_t636427523447579562.py", line 32, in  tentativa = int(input())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

---

```
import random
import sys

controlo = 0
numero = 134+78



while controlo<3:
    tentativa = int(input())

    if tentativa == numero:
        print("Acertou")
        break
    else:
         controlo +=1
         continue

if controlo == 3:
    print("Falhou")
    sys.exit()



controlo = 0

random_1 = random.randrange(1, 100)
random_2 = random.randrange(1, 100)
soma = random_1 + random_2

while controlo<3:
    tentativa_2 = int(input())

    if tentativa_2 == soma:
         print("Acertou")
         break
    else:
            controlo +=1
            continue

if controlo == 3:
    print("Falhou")
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Maybe try unindenting the lines `controlo +=1, continue` at the end of your code

Answer (score 0):

Change of the below line may fix your problem

tentativa = int(input())

read = input()

now you can check here whether 'read' is digit or mix with character
add a if condition and check

tentative = int(read)

Comment: In Python there is no difference between these two syntaxs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using Python 2 here not Python 3 as your tag suggests.

In Python 2 input() waits for the user to enter some text and then tries to execute it.  If you press 'Enter' input() will give an EOF error.  I assume that is what has happened here as your code works if numbers are entered.  I suggest using Python 3 or raw_input() in Python 2.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025920/why-input-gives-an-error-when-i-just-press-enter) for more.

Comment: I am using Python 3.6